# For improper multiple integrals, can divergence be concluded if one of the inner integrals diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

While solving

$$ \iint\limits_{(-\infty, +\infty)} \dfrac{\cos(x^2 + y^2)}{e^{x^2+ y^2}} \, \, dx dy$$

I reached the following stage after passing to polar coordinates:

$$  \iint\limits_{(-\infty, +\infty)} \dfrac{\cos(r^2)}{e^{r^2}} \, \, rdr \, d\theta = \dfrac12\iint\limits_{(-\infty, +\infty)} \dfrac{\cos(u)}{e^{u}} \, \, du \,d\theta
$$

Now, since there is no $\theta$ variable in the integrand, if we choose to integrate first with respect to $\theta$ then our partial integral is automatically divergent. 
Thus my question is,

> Is the divergence of at least one of the inner integrals in a multiple
>   integral enough to conclude that the whole multiple integral diverges?

Comment: Your polar coordinates are wrong, the integration after passing to $(\theta, r) $ is on $[0,2\pi)\times (0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Jose27 I see where I missed it, thanks.

Comment: Ok, you had a computational mistake, but the answer to your original question is: you can conclude that the integral is not **absolutely** convergent. For, if it were absolutely convergent, you could apply Fubini and reach a contradiction. However, the integral might be convergent in some weaker sense.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I was indeed basing my hypothesis on Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{\cos(x^2+y^2)}{\exp(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy = 2\pi\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{+\infty}\frac{\rho\cos(\rho^2)}{\exp(\rho^2)}\,d\rho=\pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos(z)e^{-z}\,dz = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}}. $$